# Is it possible to use a variable in form action? Html

Tags: html

Code is the variable with the URL in it.

That's how it is supposed to work: User enters code (ex: 123342) in Textbox and the Text inside the text box is saved inside variable Code. Then, its goes to the website page 123342.

```html
<form  for="Code" action='https://website.com/ + Code'>
    //makes a label 
    <label for="Answer" >URL:</label>
    <input type="Answer" id="Code" Answer="Answer"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Join" class="Join">
</form>
```

Comment: research JavaScript

Comment: Well, you can do it… but it doesn’t make sense. Actions should point to a single file that makes something with the data provided by the form: you’d better store the input value to a variable, then do more with it. It’s complicated to explain here from scratch.

Comment: Comments in HTML are not starting with `//`

Answer (score 0):

You can set it at onload:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var id = 789
    document.getElementById("form").action = "https://test.com/"+id
};
```

```html
<form  for="Code" id="form">
    <label for="Answer" >URL:</label>
    <input type="Answer" id="Code" Answer="Answer">
    <input type="submit" value="Join" class="Join">
 </form>
```